# pcap_stats and pcap_dump_open dont't work together

Tags: c++, pcap

i have the following problem. I build a c++ program with two threads.
On the parent thread i send some raw ethernet frames and in the child thread all the libpcap stuff is running.

For the output i use ncurses.

Now I have the following problem.
I can use only pcap_stats or pcap_dump_open.

When I comment out all the pcap_stats stuff the program runs regular.
All packages are captured and saved to a file.

When I comment out all the save to file stuff the program runs regular.

As soon as I use both I get an segmentation fault on pcap_dump_open.
Did i missed something?

```
void *pcapFunction(void * arg)
{
  optionList *oLT = (optionList*) arg;
  pcap_t *descr;                                              /* session descriptor */
  pcap_dumper_t *fdescr;                                      /* save file descriptor */
  struct pcap_stat ps;
  char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];                              /* error string */
  char *finalSaveFileName;
  std::string saveFileName = std::string("../pcapSaveFiles/pcapSaveFile");
  std::stringstream out;
  int capturedPackages = 0;
  time_t t;                                                   /* time structur */
  t = time(0);                                                /* get time */

  // i set up pcap the following way
  descr = pcap_create(oLT->get_deviceName(), errbuf);
  if(descr == NULL)
  {
     mvwprintw(oLT->getTopWin(), oLT->get_writeTopRow(), oLT->get_writeTopCol(), "ERROR: device could not be opend");
     oLT->refreshTopScreen();
     exit(1);
  }
  pcap_set_promisc(descr, 0);
  pcap_set_snaplen(descr, BUFSIZ);
  pcap_set_timeout(descr, 1000);
  pcap_setnonblock(descr, 0, errbuf);
  pcap_activate(descr);

  // some file name building stuff
  ...
  saveFileName = out.str();
  fdescr = pcap_dump_open(descr, strcpy(finalSaveFileName, saveFileName.c_str()));

  while (!oLT->get_stopCapture())
  {
    capturedPackages += pcap_dispatch(descr, 1, &pcap_dump, (unsigned char*) fdescr);
    // here is the problem
    pcap_stats(descr, &ps);
    // this should be the output from ps an not 
    mvwprintw(oLT->getBotWin(), 2, (oLT->get_windowCol()-18)/2, "number of captured %d packages", capturedPackages);
oLT->refreshBotScreen();
  }

  //
  pcap_dump_close(fdescr);
  pcap_close(descr);
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: Make sure you're checking the return value of `pcap_dispatch()`; it can return -1 on an error and -2 if, in a signal handler or another thread, `pcap_breakloop()` was called.  That's probably not the cause of the problem, but it's still something you need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strcpy()` doesn't work the way you think it does.

It does *not* allocate a buffer large enough to hold the result of the copy; it assumes that the buffer *already exists* and, if it's too small, it will just overwrite the data past the end of the buffer.  You do not appear to be setting the value of `finalSaveFileName`, which you would *have* to do before passing it as the first argument to `strcpy()`.

It is also not *necessary* in this case; the `c_str` method of a String returns a C string, and you can pass that C string to `pcap_dump_open()`.

If you were not setting the value of `finalSaveFileName` somewhere in code you didn't show us, then the fact that your program appeared to work, without the call to `pcap_stats()`, was through pure luck.  Perhaps, for example, whatever random value happened to be in the register, or memory location, held the value of `finalSaveFileName` happened to point to something that, when overwritten by `strcpy()`, didn't cause an immediate problem, but happened to overlap `struct pcap_stat ps`, so that if you call `pcap_stats()`, the string is overwritten, and perhaps no longer has a terminating `\0`, so that the reference to the string failed.

What you need to do, to open the output file, is

```
fdescr = pcap_dump_open(descr, saveFileName.c_str());
```

or, if you need `finalSaveFileName` to point to a copy of the C-string value of `saveFileName`, do

```
finalSaveFileName = strdup(saveFileName.c_str());
fdescr = pcap_dump_open(descr, finalSaveFileName);
```